# Black Object in Render Image

Tags: rendering, image

So I'm doing the cartoon house tutorial and am almost finished. I just have one problem. Every time I get the rendered image one of the bricks appeared to be black while the others aren't even though they're all connected. Is there something that I accidentally clicked or something?[image: This is the picture that I get every time I rendered an image][image: Before rendering all of the bricks are in the same color]

Blend File
[image]

Comment: can you share your blend file https://blend-exchange.com

Comment: I did just now.

Comment: you uploaded the backup file `.blend1` instead of the regular `.blend` file. i could still open the backup file but don't see the black brick anomaly on blender 3.1. maybe try to upload the `.blend` file instead.

Comment: What about now?

Comment: ah easy fix. there is an overlapping of bricks. just take the duplicate brick out. just move them around and you'll see 3 overlapping bricks

Answer (score 0):

The brick is doubled, thats why it is black. Delete the brick.